# How can I get access to Pike's Landing? Achievement: A little Clammy

Tags: achievements, farmville-country-escape

I would like to get the Google Play achievement but I don't see it anywhere. I am level 52.

I understand I am lacking some requirements for it.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the achievement?

Comment: Yes i have it in spanish but I'll attach it

Comment: I made an "international" edit. I can't find many information about this, do you have any water plot unlocked? Zynga's official blog just says you can meet him at Level 30.

Comment: I have two water plots, there are 2 more to go, maybe it's that? Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: As far as I know, Pike's Landing is located on the Waterfront. Can you access it?

Comment: Do you have an image? I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pike's Landing is located on the Waterfront, next to the World Class Wharf:

[image]

Comment: I have Boat Club Races there instead: https://zyngablog.typepad.com/farmville_2/2018/08/the-boat-club-races-are-here.html

Comment: @achecopar ok, my source is clearly outdated...

Comment: It seems this game has at least 2 achievements you cannot get anymore! I also asked  a question about the Specials one, maybe it is also lost.